# Is there a way to set [disabled] with help from a custom validation

Tags: angular, validation

I have a custom validation for if a condition is true. Based on that condition I would like to set disabled on a input field in a formgroup. 
If I use the condition with *ngIf it works fine but if I use the same condition with [disabled]= nothing is happening.

```
// working part
<div *ngIf="groupForm.errors?.validateForMr && (groupForm.touched || groupForm.dirty)" class="cross-validation-error-message alert alert-danger">
    Name cannot match alter ego.
</div>

// and the part I can't get to work
<input type="text" [disabled]="!groupForm.errors?.validateForMr" id="mr_nr" class="form-control" formControlName="mr_nr" (focus)="focusIn(2)" (focusout)="focusOut(2)">
```

Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: `[disabled]="!(groupForm.errors?.validateForMr && (groupForm.touched || groupForm.dirty))"` ? , not the same condition, did you try that.

Comment: Yes. It doesn't respond at all

Comment: Issue with attribute binding use `[attr.disabled]="(!groupForm.errors?.validateForMr) ? true : null"`

Comment: Try `[attr.disabled]`
instead

Comment: Provide a stackblitz please.

Comment: ranjit patra Now it works! It is the true or null response. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is not wise to disable formControl in html page..

If you are using Reactiveforms you can try this code in your Component.

`this.yourFormName.controls['yourFormControlName'].disable();` to disable input
and `this.yourFormName.controls['yourFormControlName'].enable();` to enable back.